# bash set variable with colon (:) and dash (-) in it (as used by lftp)

Tags: environment-variables, special-characters, lftp

so [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) uses some weird shell variables, like the following:

`xfer:log-file = 1`

`sftp:connect-program = “ssh -a -x -i keyfile”`

how would I set these variables? I've tried using `set`, and `env`; as well as  just straight `xfer:log-file=1` - but none of those seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think those are lftp config options, not environment variables. You set those values in the `lftp.conf` files

Comment: I know they can also be set with `lftp -e ""`, but that doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are not shell variables, they are `lftp` configuration variables, variables set for `lftp` at the `lftp` CLI prompt or in `lftp` configuration files, they have nothing to do with any *shell* (unless you want to consider `lftp` itself as a shell as it's somehow an interpreter for a shell-like language and can even execute commands with its `!` operator (though it relies on a real shell for that)).

If you want shell variables to be defined with the same name (but why would you?), beware that most shells have a lot of restrictions on what characters the name of their variables may contain.

For most shells, variable names start with a letter or underscore (can be ASCII letters or alphabetical characters as defined by your locale in some shells) and consist only of letters, decimal digits and underscore.

Some shells like `rc` or `es` allow any character (except `=` (for `rc`) and NUL) in the variable name:

```
; a:b = c
; echo $'a:b'
c
```

`bash`, `yash` and some versions of `zsh` allow characters classified as alphabetical in your locale, so you could possibly trick those shells into accepting `:` as a valid variable name character by constructing a custom locale where `:` is classified as alphabetical, but that would be a rather bad idea and is sure to break things (for instance `${var:something}` already has a special meaning in `bash` and `zsh`).

Now *environment* variable names can contain any character but NUL and `=`. So you can pass an environment variable to a command that contains `:` or `-`:

```
$ env foo:bar=baz printenv foo:bar
baz
```

but note that shells (except `rc`/`es`) won't be able to use them and some shells may even remove them from the environ (and that will not affect `lftp` which doesn't map environment variables to its configuration variables AFAIK).

---

To set those `lftp` variables upon start-up, you can do:

```
lftp -e 'set xfer:log-file transfer.log' sftp://server/
```

Or embed it in a lftp-script for non-interactive use:

```
lftp -c '
   set xfer:log-file transfer.log
   get https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240502'
```

Or

```
#! /usr/bin/lftp -f
set xfer:log-file transfer.log
get https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240502
```

Or you can add those variable definitions to your `~/.lftp/rc`.

Comment: so, using `lftp -e "...;...;...;" `, would I just use `lftp -e "set xfer:log-file 1; mirror ..."`? Because I tried that and it wasn't working

Comment: @simonalexander2005, `lftp -e "set xfer:log-file transfer.log; get https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240502"` works for me (or use `-c` instead of `-e` if you don't want to stay in `lftp` afterwards).